# jQuery.draggable() disable horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollbar

How to Disable horizontal scrolling?
overflow-x: hidden, doesn't work for me. I wanna drag the lightblue square into the pink field and I need vertical scrolling, but when I enable it the draggable get's caught in the left div.

Here's a fiddle which shows my Problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/2hzxpm3y/

```
<div class="left">
  <div class="draggable"></div>
</div>

<div class="right">

</div>

.draggable {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.left {
  float: left;
}
```

here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j0gjha95/)

Comment: @koin please see the js fiddle

Comment: happy to help:)

Comment: oh sry it breaks when i want a scrollbar on the .left div

Comment: thats because overflow is hidden in .parent class

Comment: yes but I need vertical scroll on .left and still be able to drag draggables to right div

Comment: @koin all you can do is set overflow-y:scroll in .parent class or I do not think its possible